# Manipulating the data received from Facebook queries\API calls

Tags: facebook, apache-flex, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I playing with facebook api a bit, and theres aomething that is a bit of a problem, im using Multiquerying, to get all pages a user liked. 
so i make one call to get all pages a user liked, and than a nother call to get the names of the pages. I end up with 2 lists, one is page_ids and one page_names:

```
queries.add("SELECT uid,page_id,created_time FROM page_fan WHEREuid="+userId,"page_likes");
queries.add("SELECT name,page_url FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #page_likes)","pagedata");
```

Is there a way that instead of displaying 2 lists, ill get one list with that shows page name under his page id? something like this:
 "123214211"-> "coca", "123213"->"pepsi"

that would so much useful than just 2 lists, that you need to connect between them.
Lets say i need to get comments of photos, so ill have one query for photos, second query for comments. But how will i know which comments fits to what photo?

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 1):

I haven't personally used Facebook's API, but from having looked it over here's what I can say.  They don't allow multiple tables/entities to be identified in a single query, and from what I can see that means there's no way to use a JOIN of any sort in the query which is basically what you're asking for.  Pretty much all relational database systems have the ability to do a JOIN but I think Facebook has probably chosen to not allow this option to be sure that third parties using their APIs wouldn't create overly complex SQL that would take their servers more time to process.  I think you're going to just have to write a AS3 method that deals with doing the combination of the two lists, I believe this could be written in a generic way where it could be re-used throughout without modification of the method.  My suggestion would be to make a "wrapper class" that has two properties, one with a declared type of Object and one typed as a Collection of some sort.  I'd suggest the following (in pseudo code, written as close to reality as I can without actually testing :) ):

```
public class JoinWrapper
{
    public var originalObject:Object;
    public var childrenCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
}

public class JoinUtil
{

    public static function joinThings(query1Results:ArrayCollection, query1JoinProperty:String, query2Results:ArrayCollection, query2JoinProperty:String):ArrayCollection
    {
        var tempCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        for each(var object:Object in query1Results)
        {
            var jw:JoinWrapper = new JoinWrapper();
            jw.originalObject = object;
            for each(var anotherObject:Object in query2Results)
            {
                if(object[query1JoinProperty]==anotherObject[query2JoinProperty])
                    jw.childrenCollection.addItem(anotherObject);
            }
            tempCollection.addItem(jw);
        }
        return tempCollection
    }
}
```